# Actionbar (android.support.v7) fills the entire screen

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I have given a custom theme, different style.xml for API levels "7-13" and "14 and above"

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <!-- Setting values in the default namespace affects API levels 7-13 -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/CustomTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <!-- Setting values in the default namespace affects API levels 7-13 -->
    <item name="background">@color/medium_turquoise</item>
</style>
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarSize">200dp</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/back_button_actionbar</item>
```

I have set the theme of my application as "@style/CustomTheme" and in my activity i have set following.

```
addView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar, null);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(addView);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

[image]

The entire screen has been taken by the action bar, I tried to change the height but of no use. I guess I am doing some mistake with the style.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be perfectly fine to me. Maybe Genymotion is not rendering it properly. Try running it on actual device or emulator in sdk.

Also one suggestion, if you are making a custom theme in android then try to avoid defining same style attribute again. see below

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Setting values in the default namespace affects API levels 7-13 -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/CustomTheme</item>
    <item name="background">@color/medium_turquoise</item>
    <item name="actionBarSize">200dp</item>
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/back_button_actionbar</item>
</style>
```

[image: Screenshot on nexus 5]

Comment: can u include your action bar xml file for more clarity?